# Android: show all registered alarms from alarm manager

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I would like to get all registered alarms from my alarm manager.

I found here a possible way

> For debugging purposes, you can use `adb shell dumpsys alarm` from the console.

I send this command from my Android Studio console, but I get the message:

> bash: adb: command not found

and I found this way:

```
final String tag_alarm = "tag_alarm";
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.alarmclock/alarm");
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
Log.i(tag_alarm, "no of records are " + c.getCount());
Log.i(tag_alarm, "no of columns are " + c.getColumnCount());
if (c != null) {
    String names[] = c.getColumnNames();
    for (String temp : names) {
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            for (int j = 0; j < c.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                Log.i(tag_alarm, c.getColumnName(j)
                        + " which has value " + c.getString(j));
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

but than I get this log:

> E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.android.alarmclock

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: basically there is no such `ContentProvider` associated with Uri:  `"content://com.android.alarmclock/alarm"`, where can you see it in the SDK?

Comment: i don't know. i found only this code and tried it

Comment: i only need a solution to show all registered alarms. which solution is not important for my - i should only works xD