# Why does AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo catch silent alarms from Tasker?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, tasker

I am developing a clock app that needs to get the next Alarm triggering time. By "Alarm" I mean the noisy ones to wake up. I do this with

```
 AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo aci = ((AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)).getNextAlarmClock();
```

The problem is that my app is catching Tasker "alarms" (that I have no idea where they come from), instead of the usual Clock alarms.

How do I catch a "true" noisy clock alarm? Or how do I tell AlarmManager to ignore Tasker alarms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AlarmManager` is for setting some actions to be performed at certain moment by apps. This may be "true noisy alarm" or any other action, e.g. showing reminder notification or do some sync with servers in background. check out some related [DOC](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms)

There is no such thing like "system alarm" - you have some clock app installed on your device and it have feature to set "true noisy alarm" in the future. It may use `AlarmManager` for getting informed that time for making noise comes, but may also use any other mechanism, like `WorkManager`

So there is no way/API for getting information about "true noisy alarms" set in system. Because such thing doesn't exists, alarm is a feature of app, you may have few clock apps, you may uninstall all available on device. One and only chance for getting list of "true noisy alarms" is to communicate with setting-alarms-app in any way (broadcast? aidl?), I very doubt any app this type is providing any api for this check...

Comment: I see... It makes sense. But, then, `AlarmManager.getNextAlarmClock()` is kind of useless? It can show you just anything.

Comment: Is there a way to use `AlarmManager.getNextAlarmClock()` or something similar to filter the alarms (say, to ignore the ones set by Tasker)? Or, better, to get the `NextAlarmClock()` that actually produces noise? Using `adb shell dumpsys alarm` I can see lots of info.

Comment: to be honest I'm seeing this method first time, never used that... (and lastly I've used `AlarmManager` for refreshing [app widget](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/appwidgets) with custom delays changing during day, without any noise). Maybe there is a method returning all alarms set in system, then you could filter them, but note that every manufacturer is giving user own clock app, which is different, have different package name and you probably can't be 100% sure that alarm set in `AlarmManager` is "true noisy alarm", not some background sync call or any "internal" feature

Comment: Here there is an interesting way to find the active alarm times of specific apps (it does work at least for Samsung's clockpackage): https://stackoverflow.com/q/34239005/1483390

Comment: thats the way similar to mentioned in my prev comment - some "hacky" way, which can work on particular models or even all from same manufacturer, but still its not reliable. I would suggest checking if linked way is working on newest Samsung devices (e.g. S22) and some older with oldest Android version you are planing to support (e.g. 8 years old S6, which got Android 8)

Comment: Yes, it is working fine in a Note 10 Lite with Android 13. But of course only works with (some?) Samsung models, the ones with `com.samsung.sec.android.clockpackage`.

Comment: You were right @snachmsm: not reliable. For some reason it is not working anymore (Feb 12, 2023). When trying `Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(clockuri, null, null, null, null))` the app crashes with  `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial [...] requires com.sec.android.app.clockpackage.permission.READ_ALARM or com.sec.android.app.clockpackage.permission.WRITE_ALARM`. Even after setting these permissions in the manifest, the app crashes.

Comment: I remember now that today it was an update to Samsung clock app. :/